# Retention analysis in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to analyze the users who have purchased within 30 days of their first purchase. I keep getting

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':: date) - integer '30' AND     i.customer_id = o.customer_id group by o.custome' at line 7

This is the code I've ran.

```
select 
o.customer_id, 
o.purchase_time
from orders as o
join orders as i on 
i.purchase_time <= o.purchase_time AND
i.purchase_time >= (o.purchase_time :: date) - integer '30' AND
i.customer_id = o.customer_id
group by o.customer_id, o.purchase_time;
```

Comment: I assume you are using MySQL, so the syntax doesn't work for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this is what you want, in MySQL syntax:

```
select o.*
from orders o
where exists (select 1
              from orders o2
              where o2.customer_id = o.customer_id and
                    o2.purchase_time > o.purchase_time and
                    o2.purchase_time <= purchase_time + interval 30 day
            );
```